# How do I redirect from a Django DetailView when the specified object doesn't exist?

Tags: django, detailview

So, right now when my DetailView subclass doesn't find an object using the PK (which is taken from the URL), I see the 404.html template page. What I'd rather do is just redirect to another URL. Here's my url patterns:

```
url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', DeviceDetailView.as_view(
    template_name='devices/detail.html',
    queryset=Device.objects.all(),
    context_object_name="device",
)),
url(r'^$', FullListView.as_view(template_name='devices/devices.html',)),
```

So, if my url looks like /devices/8/, it uses 8 as the primary key. Works great when 8 exists in the database. However, when 8 doesn't exist, it goes to the 404 page. What I would rather it do is go to a list - in fact, the FullListView listed when last url (which is what happens when the url looks like /devices/nonnumericstuff/.

Seems like that should be pretty easy, no? I don't want all 404's to go there so i can't use handler404.

Comment: I should mention that the urlpatterns snippet above is from a urls.py that's included from the main urls.py which is how the /devices/ part is added.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Redirect from Generic View DetailView in Django](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6456586/redirect-from-generic-view-detailview-in-django)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The `DetailView`'s [`get_object` method](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/views/generic/detail.py#L21) raises an `Http404` exception if the object doesn't exist in the queryset. Instead of overriding the `get_object` method you could catch the exception in the view's [`get` method](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/views/generic/detail.py#L107):

```
from django.http import Http404
from django.views.generic import DetailView
from django.shortcuts import redirect

class MyDetailView(DetailView):

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            self.object = self.get_object()
        except Http404:
            # redirect here
            return redirect(url)
        context = self.get_context_data(object=self.object)
        return self.render_to_response(context)
```

Comment: It didn't work for me, I also use `def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):`.

Answer (score 6):

For common cases

```
from django.http import Http404
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.urls import reverse
from django.views.generic import DetailView


class MyDetailView(DetailView):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return super().get(request, *args, **kwargs)
        except Http404:
            return redirect(reverse('my_list_view_name'))
```

Answer (score 2):

You should redefine `def get_object(self):` of the DetailView

There's something similar in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6008808/how-to-do-a-detailview-in-django-1-3)

Comment: I found that - however, that method wants to return an object. What would I return when there is no object other than throw the 404?