# name 'self' is not defined

Tags: python, django, python-2.x

```
class customerDetailView(DetailView):
    queryset = Customer.objects.get(name=self.name) # This line give error NameError: name 'self' is not defined
    context_object_name = 'customerDetail'
    template_name = "customer.html"
    allow_empty = True

    def __init__(self, name=None, *args):
        self.name = name
```

gives an error NameError: name 'self' is not defined

Comment: Where do you think it should get `self` from?

Comment: you are using self before `__init__` is called.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6008808/how-to-do-a-detailview-in-django-1-3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're wanting to customize a `DetailView`'s queryset, the correct way to do this is override the `get_queryset()` function.  See the [documentation for DetailView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#detailview) which shows the method resolution order.  In particular, [`get_queryset()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin.get_queryset) is called.

So your code would become this:

```
class customerDetailView(DetailView):
    context_object_name = 'customerDetail'
    template_name = "customer.html"
    allow_empty = True

    def __init__(self, name=None, *args):
        self.name = name

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Customer.objects.get(name=self.name)
```

You cannot use `self` in the manner you are because a `self` does not exist at class declaration, only when an *instance* of the class is created.

Comment: d'oh, beat me to it. I just opened my laptop to write that code! +1 from me.

Answer (score 3):

You should be putting your init code inside `__init__`, not the Class body:

```
class CustomerDetailView(DetailView):
    def __init__(self, name=None):
        self.name = name
        self.queryset = Customer.objects.get(name=self.name, None)
        self.context_object_name = 'customerDetail'
        self.template_name = "customer.html"
        self.allow_empty = True
    # stuff
```

Also, as an unrelated sidenote, your code uses a mix of three different styles. Try reading [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Comment: That's not really correct, most of that code should stay outside of init. See the docs referenced in Austin's answer.

Comment: @AidanEwen ahh, I see now. I'm not massively familiar with django; I answered from a python point of view.

Comment: Love the PEP8 link - I've started using pydevd's PEP8 checker recently - it's an eye opener!